non-zero exit status for "dmetar" installation without packages to update
I'm struggling to install dmetar on my new laptop, every time I updated all the dependencies of the package and I also completely reinstalled R and R studio but I continuously receive the same error and I cannot overcome it.
I try to install dmetar using devtools
devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar")

and I got this error
> devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar")
Downloading GitHub repo MathiasHarrer/dmetar@HEAD
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\gambe\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcbSrLf\remotes20d81ed964ee\MathiasHarrer-dmetar-e49875b/DESCRIPTION' (346ms)
─  preparing 'dmetar': (4.4s)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (648ms)
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building 'dmetar_0.1.0.tar.gz'
   
Installazione pacchetto in ‘C:/Users/gambe/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(perché ‘lib’ non è specificato)
* installing *source* package 'dmetar' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dmetar'
* removing 'C:/Users/gambe/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/dmetar'
Messaggio di avvertimento:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of the package
‘C:/Users/gambe/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpcbSrLf/file20d88f02fd7/dmetar_0.1.0.tar.gz’ has a non-zero exit status

I searched the internet and found that this is often a matter of package update but I tried to update everything and also reinstalled the whole system without obtaining any effect
Can you please help me?

There is not much in the error message itself, could you try devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar", dependencies = TRUE)? The other hint: have you tried to downgrade the R version a bit? Say to 4.2.x.

Hello @GrzegorzSapijaszko and thank you for your prompt answer. I tried both this code devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar", dependencies = TRUE) and installing R 4.2.1 but I experienced the same problems, also with the package "shiny" and "MuMln".  I have also tried this devtools::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar", dependencies = TRUE, type = "binary") but experienced the same problem. Have you got any other idea? Thank you very much for your help

The Github page says to use the remotes package for installation - might be worth a try: if (!require("remotes")) {   install.packages("remotes") } remotes::install_github("MathiasHarrer/dmetar")

Hello @DavoOZ I have also tried with remotes but unfortunately the result is the same

@Lorenzo, would you mind to expand your question and share the error(s) shown while installing {MuMIn} package, please? It's a required dependency for {dmetar} and without it {dmetar} fails.

Hello @GrzegorzSapijaszko and thank you again for trying to help me. {MuMIn} package installation failed with the same non-zero exit status, but I resolved it through install.packages("MuMIn", type="binary"). Now, with R 4.2.1, I'm experiencing the same problem as R 4.4.1 posted on this page.

At least a bit of progress. What about all other dependencies? Are they already installed? The full list can be found in DESCRIPTION file.

Hello @GrzegorzSapijaszko, I've checked all the other dependencies on the file you linked, installed or updated in both R 4.2.1 and R 4.4.1, but, unfortunately, the result is the same

I'm out of ideas then..

@Lorenzo - what about downloading the source of the package (cloning from git), opening it within RStudio and try to compile it? Will it throw any (additional) error? Another workaround: Download the source and copy/paste the required function(s) you need.

@GrzegorzSapijaszko thank you for this new suggestion, I'm not very friendly with these operations, is there a sort of online tutorial about cloning and copying/pasting functions? Thank you
